# find consecutive items in list

Tags: python, list, random, indexing, sublist

with a list like this:

```
list = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
```

in **Python** how to get the **index** of the **first** element of a sub-list (**consecutive items**) in this list.

sub-lists are of variable sizes.

example of sub-lists are:

```
 ["C","D","E"],["B","C","D","E","F","G"],["G","H"], ...
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What was the result? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are there bounds on computational complexity? Are you processing large amounts of data? Is there structure to your data? If none of the above, I'm guessing some simple for loops would have solved your issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following, which assumes that the `list`, `sub_lists` are valid:

```
def isSublist(entire_list, sub_list):
    return sub_list in [entire_list[i:len(sub_list)+i] for i in range(len(entire_list) - len(sub_list))]


all_list = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
sub_lists = [["C","D","E"],["B","C","D","E","F","G"],["G","H"],["B", "D"], ["E"], ["E", "F", "H"]]

res = [all_list.index(l[0]) for l in sub_lists if isSublist(all_list, l)]
print(res)
```

Which uses list comprehensions, you can read more on that in the following link:

https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/

Comment: @ David S: your code verifies only the first element in the sub-list... not the entire consecutive elements.

Comment: @moyoumos This is what you asked for "how to get the index of the first element of a sub-list"

Comment: @ David S: all the elements of the sub-list must be within the big list in their order... not only the first element.

Comment: @moyoumos see my edit

Comment: @ David S: thanks David...yet my question is not so clear for some people...